# How to Use DCFlow to construct Control Flow Graph in Rascal?

Tags: rascal

I am new to Rascal and I am looking forward to construct Control Flow Graph for java. How to make use of DCFlow to construct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've started on but hasn't been completed yet (mainly due to a lack of time, most of my work is on PHP program analysis). Once this is fully defined I'll post it on GitHub. My goal is to build it over the M3 definition of Java since we already have the extraction code in place to generate M3 models, and these optionally include ASTs (which we need for CFG generation).